# Have complication with ArrayList of ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am implementing an algorithm,for that I need to use `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`.I want to retrieve each `ArrayList` from the Main `ArrayList`.

Eg: If the Main `ArrayList` contains 5 `ArrayList` and Each `ArrayList` in the main list contains 5 rows.

`MainArrayList`:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,a , 2,3,4,5,3,b , 7,8,9,4,5,d]    //1st Arraylist
[1,2,3,4,5,e , 2,3,4,5,3,n , 7,8,9,4,5,e]    //11nd Arraylist
[1,2,3,4,5,f , 2,3,4,5,3,t , 7,8,9,4,5,q]    //111rd Arraylist
[1,2,3,4,5,c , 2,3,4,5,3,b , 7,8,9,4,5,a]    //1vth Arraylist
[1,2,3,4,5,r , 2,3,4,5,3,m , 7,8,9,4,5,z]    //v th Arraylist
```

I need to access each `ArrayList` from the main list and print it's content row by row 
i.e for example
print 1st `ArrayList` from the main list.

```
1,2,3,4,5,a 
2,3,4,5,3,b 
7,8,9,4,5,d
```

similarly I need to print all arraylist in the main list same as above.

Comment: have you tried anything? Show your efforts.

Comment: HashMap is a good solution for whatever you are trying.

Answer (score 1):

Use `HashMap` for resolving this problem.

Comment: This is not the solution for SO problem.  This can be a comment not an answer

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using ArrayList

```
List<List<Object>> twoDimArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<>>();
twoDimArray.add(Arrays.asList("1","2","3");
for(List<Object> list: twoDimArray){
   for(Object o : list){
       System.out.println(o.toString());
   }
}
```

And of course using HashMap:

```
Map<String,List<Object>> map = new HashMap<String,List<Object>>();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())
{
   System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
}
```